# Executing a function on html page load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to execute a javascript function immediately when the page runs. I thought that this would work, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 
    //Browser Support Code
        window.onload = function runAtLoadTime() {
            getInfo;
        }

        function getInfo() {
            alert("here");
            console.log("here");
        }
   //-->
   </script>
```

Comment: When you say page run do you mean even before the DOM loads?

Comment: What's up with the -1? What's wrong with this question?

Comment: Not related to the question, but `language` attribute is deprecated, also you don't need to enclose the script within comments (unless you are using NoteTab as an editor).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Maybe a better way is to add that as a comment (as you did after I questioned the rating). That way people, including myself, learn from it. Otherwise, it just seems petty.

Comment: Hmm... It wasn't my downvote, and I think your question wasn't downvoted because of those details mentioned in my comment. Rather the downvote is for asking this kind of very basic stuff here...

Comment: Basic is a matter of perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `()` in order to call a function. Replace

```
getInfo;
```

by

```
getInfo();
```

Or taking into account that `runAtLoadTime` has no logic except for a call to `getInfo` you could simply do

```
// assign getInfo to onload, I'm not calling it here, that's why () are not used
window.onload = getInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onload` property of the `window` object accepts a function, which you have correctly assigned. However inside your function you are not performing a function call. If your event handler contains logic other than calling the `getInfo` function then use the first one. Otherwise use the second one. You have two alternatives here:

```
// Function call inside your event handler
window.onload = function runAtLoadTime() {
     getInfo();
}
```

or

```
// Assigning the function directly
window.onload = getInfo;
```